# Washed out colors in PictureBox

Tags: c#, colors, picturebox

When I show a specific image in a PictureBox (or Cyotek's ImageBox in my case, doesn't matter), the color gets a little washed out. Most images displays correctly but some few images gets washed out.

Here's what it looks like:

[The original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tPDH.jpg)

[Opened in Windows Photo Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxjoP.jpg)

[Opened in my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVdM8.jpg)

I tried loading the image in 3 different ways, but same result:

```
Image image = GetImage(OPEN);
imgBox.Image = image;


public Image GetImage(string path)
        {
            Image image = null;
            //image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Visual Studio\pictures\pokemon.jpg");  // washed out colors
            try
            {
                using (FileStream file_stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))  // washed out colors
                {
                    MemoryStream memory_stream = new MemoryStream();
                    file_stream.CopyTo(memory_stream);
                    image = Image.FromStream(memory_stream, false, false);
                    file_stream.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                try
                {
                    FIBITMAP picture = FreeImage.LoadEx(path);  // washed out colors
                    Bitmap bitmap = FreeImage.GetBitmap(picture);
                    image = bitmap;
                    FreeImage.Unload(picture);
                }
                catch { }
            }
            return image;
        }
```

Anyone know why this is? Maybe some specific tag in this image that Windows and PictureBox handles differently?

Comment: All 3 images look exactly the same on my machine - are these posted images supposed to show the differences? If not can you show screenshots of the differences?

Comment: I can see a slight difference in saturation, try the Image.FromFile overload that has the useEmbeddedColorManagement option & enable it.

Comment: Yes the last image is a little more washed out.

Comment: Could you give an example how that should look like Alex K.?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said FromStream not FromFile: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Drawing_Image_FromStream_System_IO_Stream_System_Boolean_

Comment: Oh ok. I have a FromStream, but where do I put useEmbeddedColorManagement? This is what I got https://imgur.com/P7R9stP

Comment: Make the last 2 arguments `, true, false` instead of `, false, false`

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick! If you make that as an answer I'll accept it if you want. Thank you so much! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`Image.FromStream()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Drawing_Image_FromStream_System_IO_Stream_System_Boolean_) and pass `true` for the `useEmbeddedColorManagement` argument to ensure that any metadata for color management is used.